# UIPopoverController don't make resize

Tags: ios, resize, swift, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

I'm using UIPopoverController tho show a view, in that view I have a UIPickerView, when a use presentPopoverFromRect , the PopOverControll Shows in the x and y correct position but not resizes the control. This viewController is a separated .swift file.

```
var buttonCenter: CGPoint = BtCheque.center;            
var rect:CGRect = CGRectMake(buttonCenter.x, 1, 120, 90);                
_colorPickerPopover.presentPopoverFromRect(rect, inView: self.view , permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, animated: true);
```

The UIPickerView has the correct size, but the popUp doesn't.

This is the result:

[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AubfP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood how `presentPopoverFromRect` works, it specify rectangle from which your popover will show itself, this is not rectangle of your popover.

For example if you have a button with frame (10, 10, 100, 30) and after you press this button you want to show popover, this is the recommended frame you should pass to `presentPopoverFromRect`, not popover frame.

To specify size of your popover use `popoverContentSize` property for your `_colorPickerPopover`.

You can also set `preferredContentSize` in, for example, `viewDidLoad` method in your popover subclass.

Comment: I forgot to paste the line before set buttonCenter.  _colorPickerPopover.setPopoverContentSize(CGSizeMake(120,90), animated: true); But didn't help. And now preferredContentSize in viewDidLoad works perfect!!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually setting the size of the UIPopover, as @Greg mentions. However, I have found it best practice to set the `preferredContentSize` in `viewWillAppear`.